# Why wont Bootstrap 4 carousel allow a form inside a carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4, and am implementing a carousel. I have a carousel slide that accepts an email address in a form. However, it seems the carousel is blocking the keyboard from being used. Inside the carousel, I cannot type, only select from the list of autofill email address with my mouse. Here is the basics, unstyled, as you see, you cannot type in the form field. Thank you.

**UPDATE** Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t81zadee/

**UPDATE** Here is the fiddle removing hidden-xs-down because originally I had the carousel hidden on small screens. In reality, I don't plan on using it on small screens so the layout may not be formatted the best, but for debugging, here is the fiddle for small screens: https://jsfiddle.net/t81zadee/9/

**UPDATE** The carousel is set to pause on hoover, so having enough time to type in the field should not be a problem. As long as you don't leave the panel, it won't keep sliding. I know it's not the most ideal layout, but I still need to figure it out. I just don't understand why the carousel would block keyboard use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide hidden-xs-down" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <p>Slide irrelevant to question</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="container-fluid p-a-0">
                            <p>Slide irrelevant to question</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="container-fluid ">
                            <br><h1 class ="text-xs-center">Signup&nbsp;for&nbsp;our&nbsp;email&nbsp;list</h1><br>
                            <div class="row m-a-0">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 m-x-auto"><br>

                                    <form>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="email">e-mail address</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width:100%" id="email" placeholder="e-mail address">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-Custom2" style="width:100%">Subscribe!</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Code snippet:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide hidden-xs-down" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <p>Slide irrelevant to question</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="container-fluid p-a-0">
          <p>Slide irrelevant to question</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="container-fluid ">
          <br>
          <h1 class="text-xs-center">Signup&nbsp;for&nbsp;our&nbsp;email&nbsp;list</h1>
          <br>
          <div class="row m-a-0">
            <div class="col-xs-12 m-x-auto">
              <br>

              <form>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                  <label class="sr-only" for="email">e-mail address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" style="width:100%" id="email" placeholder="e-mail address">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-Custom2" style="width:100%">Subscribe!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jsfiddle please. Otherwise I can't see anything.

Comment: ok, I will give me a minute, never created one before, just looked at them.

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t81zadee/

Comment: It'll help others help you more if you add it to your question. Edit it and add :)

Comment: The jsfiddle appears blank. I'm trying on mobile. Do you see something?

Comment: yeah in my code, I have hidden-xs-down, because originally I don't use it on xs, I'll see if I can remove it for the question.

Comment: Updated fiddle to show on xs screens: https://jsfiddle.net/t81zadee/9/ also edited question to add fiddles

Comment: I'm not surprised it doesn't allow input, unless the slide show is meant to stop as soon as I tap the input field, because otherwise I would not have a chance to put my email by the time it moves on to the next slide.

Comment: But I do see what you mean

Comment: it intercepts the arrow buttons for next and previous. Setting `data-keyboard="false"` will help.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#options) first.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Mathew Jibin, adding data-keyboard="false" to the carousel div allowed form field typing in the carousel.